# Is jOOQ's fetchLazy() truly lazy?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jooq

I'm using jOOQ 3.4.2 to query a PostgreSQL database using Scala. I want to fetch small chunks of the result set at a time without loading the entire result set into memory, as the query could return many rows. I have the following code:

```
val query = context.selectFrom(table)
                   .where(conditions)
                   .orderBy(orderField)
                   .fetchSize(1)
val cursor = query.fetchLazy()
// Iterate through cursor using cursor.fetchOne()
```

It appears that jOOQ will load the *entire* result set (or at least a huge chunk of the result set) in memory when I call `fetchLazy()`, before I even fetch the first row from the cursor (judging by the large number of `recvfrom()` syscalls I'm seeing while `fetchLazy()` is being called). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Not from the jOOQ side. This is exactly how you ensure that both jOOQ (via [`ResultQuery.fetchLazy()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchLazy--) and [`Cursor.fetchOne()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Cursor.html#fetchOne--)) and the JDBC driver (via [`ResultQuery.fetchSize()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchSize-int-), which translates to [`PreparedStatement.setFetchSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize-int-)) will fetch exactly one row at a time.

You may, however, have run into [this PostgreSQL JDBC driver caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468140/521799), saying that for `fetchSize` to work, you have to run the query in an explicit transaction.

Comment: As far as I know, lazy queries in postgresql must be executed in a transaction for make them truly lazy. Postgresql jdbc driver uses server side cursors and them only works in a transaction.

Comment: @AndreyAntukh: Yes, that's what the linked Stack Overflow question also says. I'll quickly update my answer

Answer (score 3):

If somebody has the same problem with MySQL:

MySQL requires `fetch size` to be set to **Integer.MIN_VALUE** to indicate to the driver that the result should be fetched row-by-row: https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.9.1/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchSize

Doing this will make jOOQ's `fetchLazy()` work without loading the whole result set into memory.