# ResultSet setFetchSize() method is not working?

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am using the `ojdbc5.jar`. 
First, I am getting `DatabaseMetaData` from sql connection
Then I am calling `getProcedureColumns()` method on `DatabaseMetaData` which returns me a resultset.
When I print the fetchsize of the `resultset`, it returns 1.
Then, I tried setting this fetchsize using the method `setFetchSize()` method on the resultset.
Again, when I print the fetchSize of the `resultset`, it prints 1.
Why, the `setFetchSize()` method of the `resultset` is not working ?

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet result = metaData.getProcedureColumns(null,"IFSAPP","DECODE",null);
System.out.println(result.getFetchSize());
result.setFetchSize(100);
System.out.println(result.getFetchSize());
```

Result of the above code snippet is:
1
1

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons for that, including - for example - that the database metadata might be cached and therefor it is a disconnected result set that is fully materialized so fetch size would be irrelevant, without in depth knowledge of the implementation of the Oracle JDBC driver it is hard to tell. I suggest you try it with a normal select query instead.

Comment: according to this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/resltset.htm you have to setBatchSize before running the query. I hope it is possible (checking it...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java JDBC ignores setFetchSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468036/java-jdbc-ignores-setfetchsize)