# JOOQ fetching data from large table : good practise

Tags: java, postgresql, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, jooq

I am having an external api, one to download and other to upload data from and to db tables [postgresql]. Table is quite big. Over time, we observed that slowly server keeps on taking memory but doesn't remove it much, and it throws error and quits [sometimes linux closes it]. I checked the memory dump and I cannot figure out anything which I can relate to with my code. I don't use any local caching or something like that. But today I got this-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.sql.Timestamp.toString(Timestamp.java:350)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.name(AbstractParam.java:107)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:81)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:77)
        at org.jooq.impl.Val.<init>(Val.java:63)
        at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:15157)
        at org.jooq.impl.Tools.field(Tools.java:1092)
        at org.jooq.impl.Tools.fields(Tools.java:1226)
        at org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle.executePrepared(BatchSingle.java:231)
        at org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle.execute(BatchSingle.java:182)
        at org.jooq.impl.BatchCRUD.executePrepared(BatchCRUD.java:159)
        at org.jooq.impl.BatchCRUD.execute(BatchCRUD.java:100)
```

For fetching, I use normal `fetch` function and for dumping data into DB, I use JOOQ's `batchInsert` and `batchUpdate` methods. Is there any good practises with JOOQ to deal with large set of data? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Both `fetch()` and `batchInsert()` / `batchUpdate()` will buffer your content, i.e. your results and/or bind variables. This approach is not recommended when using jOOQ. Let's look at both operations individually:

#### Large reads

For large reads, you should avoid `fetch()` as this will get all the records from your database and store them in memory prior to consuming them. In most cases, this is the better approach than keeping open cursors / resources (the way JDBC does), but in cases where results are large, this is prohibitive. Instead, you should use [`fetchLazy()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchLazy--) or [`fetchStream()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchStream--):

```
// Using fetchLazy():
try (Cursor<Record> cursor = query.fetchLazy()) {
    ...
}

// Using fetchStream():
try (Stream<Record> stream = query.fetchStream()) {
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to use try-with-resources to ensure all resources, such as `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement` are closed when you finish.

Do note there is also [`ResultQuery.fetchSize()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchSize-int-), which allows for [specifying the JDBC fetch size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1468036/521799) to prevent the PostgreSQL JDBC driver from buffering too many rows as well.

#### Large writes

You shouldn't write huge inserts in one go in any database. Apart from the client memory issues that you may run into, there is also a risk of server-side issues related to growing UNDO/REDO logs. Ideally, you should partition your write into small chunks by fine-tuning:

- bulk size
- batch size
- commit size

jOOQ knows the `Loader` API to import CSV/JSON/array data and to take care of the above fine-tuning. It is documented here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing